# how to update setdatasource of running mediaplayer in android

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I create a mp3 file by writing OutputStream(Bytes array) and then put mp3 file path in setDataSource of media player then media player is start.

But when I update running mp3 file by appending stream(Bytes array) at runtime then media player is not updated. So how can I solve this issue.
please help regarding this issue.

Here is my code:

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream dataOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();     
int count=0
    while(true){
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1096*50];
                int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                String fpath = "/sdcard/" + "sha" + ".txt";
                File file = new File(fpath);
                // If file does not exists, then create it

    if (!file.exists()) {                             
                        file.createNewFile();
                        }
    try{

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fpath);
        dataOutputStream.writeTo(outputStream);
        count++;
           if (count==500){
               playMp3(fpath);
                          }
                 }


     private void playMp3(String path) {

        try {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            String s = ex.toString();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do post the codes you think are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

First declare the boolean variable that is need to be set when the file is appended or it is going to play next

```
 public boolean nextplay=true;
```

If there is no file(or Not appended to an existing file's end) to play then make it false

```
      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
       mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
              if(nextplay)
              {
               mp.stop();
               mp.reset();
               mp.setDataSource(second_file);
               mp.prepare();
               mp.start();
              }
              else
              {
              mp.stop();
             }
             }
             });
```

Comment: Thanks akhil. but when run this code, it gives exception

Comment: Thanks akhil. but when run this code, it gives exception in link [link](https://jpst.it/IROw)

Comment: Thank you so much akhil. above code is running but one problem by this code is  lagging. when 1st file is completed then 2nd file is start after some bit of interval.

Comment: For that you can do one thing.goto Manifest file and in <application> or <activity> tag write android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: Sorry akhil after adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in manifest file. it does not effect. lagging problem is not solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113027/discussion-between-shashank-gupta-and-akhil-rao).

Comment: Sorry akhil after adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in manifest file. it does not effect. lagging problem is not solved.